# Jquery Steps basic example

Tags: jquery, css

Trying to get started with Steps. Getting a non styled version on the page. No CSS appears to be applied. Paths to files are correct.

I hope to end up with a validated form, but can't get going with the basics.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/steps/css/jquery.steps.css">
        <script src="js/steps/build/jquery.steps.js"></script>        

</head>
<body>

<script>
$("#example-basic").steps({
    headerTag: "h3",
    bodyTag: "section",
    transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
    autoFocus: true
});
</script>

<div id="example-basic">
    <h3>Keyboard</h3>
    <section>
        <p>Try the keyboard navigation by clicking arrow left or right!</p>
    </section>
    <h3>Effects</h3>
    <section>
        <p>Wonderful transition effects.</p>
    </section>
    <h3>Pager</h3>
    <section>
        <p>The next and previous buttons help you to navigate through your content.</p>
    </section>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you give a tree of your project?

Comment: A tree? Sorry not sure what you mean. Other than the included files, this is just a basic example, the complete page.